# Laravel 6.x - Eloquent where clauses with Mutator attribute doesn't works

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello guys i'm trying to add where clause in my custom attribute "ateco" without success.

**My Model**

```
class AtcReportRule extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'intermediary_id',
            'atc_report_rule_id',
            'atc_report_kpi_id',
            'operator',
            'value',
            'important',
            'flag',
            'type'
        ];
    
        public function setAtecoAttribute()
        {
            $ruleValue = str_replace(".","", $this->value);
            preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ruleValue, $matches);
            if ( isset($matches[0][0]) ) {
                // a volte capita N.N Oppure A.A ecc
                $ruleValue = $matches[0][0];
            }
            $this->attributes['ateco'] = $ruleValue;
        }

        public function childrens() {
            return $this->hasMany('Modules\Atc\Entities\AtcReportRule','atc_report_rule_id')->orderBy("order");
        }
    
    }
```

**QUERY**

```
$ruleChildren = $atcReportRule->childrens->where("ateco","some_value")->first()
```

it return null without value. The follow code has not the attribute "ateco"

**TEST**

```
dd($atcReportRule->childrens[0])
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. Where are you trying to set the value of `AtcReportRule::$ateco` to trigger the mutator? Where is this query run?

Comment: i tried to use mutator to add a new attribute to my model. This new parameter i wil use on my query => $ruleChildren = $atcReportRule->childrens->where("ateco","some_value")->first()

Comment: i published the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your test does not return `ateco` atribute therefore your query returns null as well.

if you do:

```
$ruleChildren = $atcReportRule->childrens->where("atc_report_rule_id","some_value")->first()
```

Then it will work. Here is your solution: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

After defining accessor you need to add it to json response as well.

```
protected $appends = ['ateco'];
```

Comment: change this "setAtecoAttribute" to "getAtecoAttribute"

Comment: change this "$this->attributes['ateco'] = $ruleValue;" to "return $ruleValue;"

Answer (score 0):

**i fixed like this:**

```
/**
     * Get the user's full name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected $appends = ['ateco'];
    public function getAtecoAttribute()
    {
        $ruleValue = str_replace(".","", $this->value);
        preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ruleValue, $matches);
        if ( isset($matches[0][0]) ) {
            // a volte capita N.N Oppure A.A ecc
            $ruleValue = $matches[0][0];
        }
        return $ruleValue;
    }
```

**then i can do this:**

```
$atcReportRule->childrens->where("ateco","some_value")->first();
```